# how to grab the content without simulating clicking, python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm try to grab the course descriptions on this [page](https://dsa.missouri.edu/curriculum/). The descriptions will show after clicking the buttons, but I find they've been already written in the html. Is there any way I can grab the descriptions without simulating clicks using python selenium?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't want to click?

Comment: Not really, but I think there may be a way to not click as the contents already are in the html

Comment: What are your code trials and errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape the page & get the result using `BeautifulSoup` instead of using `selenium`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://dsa.missouri.edu/curriculum/"
req = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html5lib') 
#print(soup.prettify())

my_text= soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'kt-accordion-panel-inner'})

print(my_text.text)
```

For more about web scraping, refer [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-web-scraping-python-beautiful-soup/)